# Verification: Does symmetry of $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ imply symmetry of every derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable and in $\mathbb R^2$ (point or axially) symmetric, that means:

$$\exists a \in \mathbb R \, \forall x \in \mathbb R: f(a-x)+f(a+x)=2f(a)$$

Does that imply that every derivative is point or axially symmetric? Is there a counter example?

Comment: Did you try differentiating both sides of the equality?

Comment: Sure, that gives $f'(a+x)=f'(a-x)$... but how can I see if it's point or axially symmetric to any point or axis? Sorry, maybe I have a blonde moment right now.

Comment: @ATW How would you formally write "$f'$ is axially symmetric to the line $x=a$"?

Comment: It would be $f'(x-a)=f'(-(x-a))$. That's not the same, so it cannot be generally right?

Comment: That would make $f'$ even function, not axially symmetric wrt $x=a$.

Comment: I think that $x^3$ is a counter example, no?

Comment: @Shahar Romem Peled, counterexample to what? Its derivative is $3x^2$, rather symmetric.

Comment: No - $y = 3 x^2$ is axially symmetric.

Comment: @ATW, you should sketch an axially symmetric graph and look for a proper definition, the one you provided isn't what you want. For example, you might wanna look at $\sin$ and axis $x=\pi/2$, or some parabola, like $(x-a)^2$.

Comment: @ATW Well I know it's symmetric, but look on your formal definition, for what $a$ from your definition this works? Perhaps your formal definition is wrong here?